# "12,345" and "1.234,5" with siunitx

Tags: siunitx

`\num{12345}` formats as "12,345". That looks right. I want that thousands separator.

`\num{1.2345}` formats as "1.234,5". I'm not used to seeing the comma group separator used after the decimal like that. Is that normal? Can I disable that, while keeping it before the decimal point?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Option `group-digits=integer` helps to get groups for the integer part only:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\sisetup{
  group-separator={,},
  group-minimum-digits=4,% or group-four-digits
  group-digits=integer,
}

\begin{document}
  \num{12345}
  \num{1.2345}
\end{document}
```

> [image: Result]